# Adding criteria to filter by a self referencing parent?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, criteria

Stumped on this one. I have a many to many self referencing relationship(FluentNH) mapped for a given class:

```
public class Folder
{
    public IList<Folder> ParentFolders{get;set;}
}
```

I'm looking to create a query that pulls root folders(*ie folders that have ParentFolders.Count() == 0*). The self reference is done via lookup table, so ParentFolderID is not actually accessible from the class(only shows up in the mapping).

```
public IList<Folder> GetRootFolders()
{
    return session.CreateCriteria<Folder>()
        .outofideas()
        .List<Folder>();
}
```

Any assistance or thoughts on a self referencing hierarchy via lookup table are greatly appreciated. The tables themselves are legacy and as such, unable to be modified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your mapping has something like this:

```
<bag name="ParentFolders" table="FolderFolder" lazy="true">
    <key column="FolderID"/>
    <many-to-many class="Folder" column="ParentFolderID"/>
</bag>
```

then if you write:

```
var folders = Session.CreateCriteria<Folder>("folder")
    .Add(Restrictions.IsEmpty("ParentFolders")).List<Folder>();
```

you will get this SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM Folder folder 
WHERE not exists (select 1 from FolderFolder where folder.FolderID=FolderID)
```

that I believe does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I've always found NHibernate's `Criteria` difficult to work with. (That is to say - even *more* difficult than the rest of NHibernate.) Try creating an HQL query instead. Without seeing the mapping file I can't write the query for you, but it would be something like:

```
session.CreateQuery("FROM Folder f WHERE COUNT(f.ParentFolders) = 0")
```

You'd have to play around with the syntax a bit, I'm writing this from memory. Note that NHibernate is smart enough to do a sub-query for the COUNT - it won't actually load all your parent folders and *then* count them.